# Eliminar correctamente objetos de un json

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy realizando un código el cual consiste en agregar y eliminar elementos de un objeto en json, al agregar el elemento no tengo problemas el problema lo tengo cuando elimino uno, es decir si inicialmente tengo un objeto asi:

```json
[
 {"nombre":"PLANCHA","descripcion":"PLANCHA","img1":"https://","referencia":"PL1","precio":"210000"},
 {"nombre":"PLANCHA","descripcion":"PLANCHA","img1":"https://","referencia":"PL1","precio":"210000"},
 {"nombre":"PLANCHA","descripcion":"PLANCHA","img1":"https://","referencia":"PL1","precio":"210000"}
]
```

Si elimino el valor del medio con un `delete` y la llave:

```javascript
let zf = JSON.parse(objeto) 
delete zf[i]
```

Al eliminar me quedaría así:

```json
[
 {"nombre":"PLANCHA","descripcion":"PLANCHA","img1":"https://","referencia":"PL1","precio":"210000"},
 null,
 {"nombre":"PLANCHA","descripcion":"PLANCHA","img1":"https://","referencia":"PL1","precio":"210000"}
]
```

El problema es que no se como quitar ese `null` y que quede el objeto normal

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `.splice()` ya que tus elementos están dentro de un arreglo.

```js
const arreglo = [{
    "nombre": "PLANCHA1",
    "descripcion": "PLANCHA",
    "img1": "https://",
    "referencia": "PL1",
    "precio": "210000"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "PLANCHA2",
    "descripcion": "PLANCHA",
    "img1": "https://",
    "referencia": "PL1",
    "precio": "210000"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "PLANCHA3",
    "descripcion": "PLANCHA",
    "img1": "https://",
    "referencia": "PL1",
    "precio": "210000"
  }
]

arreglo.splice(1, 1)
console.log(arreglo)
```

> ## [.`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
>
> El método `splice()` cambia el contenido de un array eliminando elementos existentes y/o agregando nuevos elementos.

Comment: Voy a probarlo gracias